# DATEADD in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm using `DATEADD` statement in **SQL Server** and I need migration to **MariaDB**

```
  SUM (
    CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(varchar, Production.MadeDate , 112) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DAY, -2, '2018-06-05') AND DATE_ADD(DAY, -2, '2018-06-05') THEN
      Production.Qty
    ELSE
      0
    END
  ) AS 'N-2'
```

And i got error like this

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'varchar, Production.MadeDate , 112) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DAY,
>   -2, '2018-06-05') AND ' at line 3

I'm got references from [MariaDB DATE_ADD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date_add/) and [MariaDB ADDDATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/adddate/) but it's still doesn't working

My Version MariaDB `10.1.32-MariaDB`

EDIT :

**[SOLVED]**

Changing the **SQL Statment** from `CONVERT` to `CAST`

```
  SUM (
    CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(varchar, Production.MadeDate , 112) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DAY, -2, '2018-06-05') AND DATE_ADD(DAY, -2, '2018-06-05') THEN
      Production.Qty
    ELSE
      0
    END
  ) AS 'N-2'
```

**TO**

```
SUM (
    CASE WHEN CAST(Production.MadeDate AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2018-06-05', INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND DATE_ADD('2018-06-05', INTERVAL -2 DAY) THEN
        Production.Qty
    ELSE
        0
    END
) AS 'N-2'
```

It's working for me on

```
10.1.32-MariaDB
```

Comment: I don't understand what your `WHERE` clause is supposed to be checking.  Logically speaking, the date range is the same date on both ends.  Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: And why do you convert the Date to a VarChar before comparing it to a Date?

Comment: @dnoeth - perhaps to get rid of the time portion?

Comment: @RickJames: Yep, probably a DateTime in SQL Server. But then  `CAST(timestampCol AS DATE)` is way simpler :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `CONVERT` like this on MariaDB / MySQL:

```
CONVERT(varchar, Production.MadeDate, 112)
```

The order of the parameters isn't valid on MariaDB / MySQL. The order of the parameters looks like [TSQL / SQL Server syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles).

So you can replace the current `CONVERT` with one of the following:

```
CONVERT(Production.MadeDate, DATE)  -- using CONVERT (ODBC syntax)
CAST(Production.MadeDate AS DATE)   -- using CAST (SQL92 syntax)
```

You can use the following `SUM` using [`CAST`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/cast/) and [`DATE_ADD`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date_add/):

```
SUM (
    CASE WHEN CAST(Production.MadeDate AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2018-06-05', INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND DATE_ADD('2018-06-05', INTERVAL -2 DAY) THEN
        Production.Qty
    ELSE
        0
    END
) AS 'N-2'
```

**Note:** Check the condition on `CASE WHEN` also. You check between the same days.

Comment: So i can't use CONVERT? How about DATE_ADD?

Comment: @Aldan: Well, you found the entry in the MariaDB manual for `DATE_ADD`, I doubt they will add it without supporting it.

Comment: Sebastian Brosch and dnoeth thanks a lot, it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

In no database should you be converting date/time values to strings for comparison.  I also discourage the use of `BETWEEN`.  So, I would expect something like this in MariaDB:

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN Production.MadeDate >= '2018-06-05' - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND
               Production.MadeDate < '2018-06-05' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
          THEN Production.Qty
          ELSE 0
     END) AS N_2
```

In SQL Server, I would write this as:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Production.MadeDate >= DATEADD(day, -2, '2018-06-05') AND
              Production.MadeDate < DATEADD(day, -1, '2018-06-05')
         THEN Production.Qty
         ELSE 0
    END) AS N_2
```

Note the changes:

- All comparisons are done using native date/time types.
- The `N-2` is changed to `N_2`, so the column alias does not need to be escaped.
- The date/time comparisons are made using direct comparisons, rather than `BETWEEN`.